# AWS SNS Push Notification getting delayed or not sending

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am working on an application where we have to send a silent notification every 5 or 10 seconds to all the subscribers of SNS topic XYZ.

I am publishing some messages to SNS topic XYZ from the backend every 5 or 10 seconds.

Suppose 15 users (using the FCM token) subscribe to SNS topic XYZ.

I have monitored cloudwatch logs.

So what's happening is that sometimes notifications are sent to 10 users, 5 users, or even just 2 users.

and we send notifications every 5 or 10 seconds, so ideally 6 times per minute, but notifications are sometimes sent every 2 minutes, 1 minute, or 2 minutes.

Below is the sample code I am using for sending push notifications to the SNS XYZ topic.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
  region: 'YOUR_REGION'
});

const sns = new AWS.SNS();

let payload = {
    default: "This is the content of the push notification",
    GCM: {
      notification: {
        content_available: true,
      },
      data: {
        body: "some data",
        title: "Hello world",
        sound: "default",
      },
    },
  };

payload.GCM = JSON.stringify(payload.GCM);
payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

const params = {
  Message: payload,
  MessageStructure: "json",
  TopicArn: 'YOUR_TOPIC_ARN'
};

sns.publish(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

We are trying to send notifications every 5–10 seconds to all the subscribers of SNS topic XYZ.

and frequency should be maintained; suppose 10 users have subscribed to a SNS topic; then notification should be sent to all 10 users.